# Objective-C Completion Block

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm having some issues understanding how to call methods with completion block to as NSURLSessionTask.  Wondering how I would properly call the method getForecastAndConditionsForZipCode without an error.  Thank you!

Api.h:

```
 typedef void (^WeatherAPICompletionBlock)(BOOL success, NSDictionary *result, NSError *error);

 - (NSURLSessionDataTask *)getForecastAndConditionsForZipCode:(NSString *)zipCode withCompletionBlock:(WeatherAPICompletionBlock)completionBlock;
```

Api.m

```
 - (NSURLSessionDataTask *)getForecastAndConditionsForZipCode:(NSString *)zipCode withCompletionBlock:(WeatherAPICompletionBlock)completionBlock
 {
if (!self.APIKey) {
    NSAssert(NO, @"API Key not set", nil);
    completionBlock(NO, nil, [self missingAPIKeyError]);
    return nil;
}

if (![NSThread isMainThread]) {
    NSAssert(NO, @"API client method must be called on the main thread", nil);
    completionBlock(NO, nil, [self genericError]);
    return nil;
}

// Create the path
NSString *pathString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/api/%@%@/q/%@.json", self.APIKey, kWeatherAPIConditionsPath, zipCode];

// To avoid a retain cycle
__weak __typeof(self)weakSelf = self;

// Start the request

return [self GET:pathString parameters:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
 if (!responseObject || ![responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] || [responseObject count] == 0) {
        DLog(@"Invalid responseObject: %@", responseObject);
        completionBlock(NO, nil, [weakSelf genericError]);
        return;
    }
    completionBlock(YES, responseObject, nil);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
    DLog(@"Error with getForcastForLocation response: %@", error);
    completionBlock(NO, nil, error);
}];
```

}

ViewController.m (here is where I don't understand how to call the getForecastAndConditionsForZipCode method

import "Api.h"

```
 - (IBAction)runApi:(UIButton *)sender {

  WeatherAPIClient *weatherApiClient = [[WeatherAPIClient alloc] init];

  NSURLSessionDataTask *test =  [weatherApiClient getForecastAndConditionsForZipCode:@"55345" withCompletionBlock:^(YES, result, error)];

 }
```

Comment: Seriously, can you change the title of your question?

Comment: @gnasher729, you have an "objection" to his title? I fail to C your objection. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use code completion in Xcode to make this simple.

Type:

```
NSURLSessionDataTask *test =  [weatherApiClient getForecast
```

and select the matching method name. Then tab to the placeholder after `withCompletionBlock:` and press return. Magically you will end up with:

```
NSURLSessionDataTask *test =  [weatherApiClient getForecastAndConditionsForZipCode:@"55345" withCompletionBlock:^(BOOL success, NSDictionary *result, NSError *error) {
}];
```

Now you need to fill in the part between the curly braces. That is the block that you want called when processing is completed. You will be given the values for `success`, `result`, and `error`. You probably want something like:

```
NSURLSessionDataTask *test =  [weatherApiClient getForecastAndConditionsForZipCode:@"55345" withCompletionBlock:^(BOOL success, NSDictionary *result, NSError *error) {
    if (success) {
        // do something with result
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Uh oh - error getting forecast: %@", error);
    }
}];
```

BTW - your implementation of the `getForecastAndConditionsForZipCode:withCompletionBlock:` should not assume a completion block was passed in. Be sure you guard all calls to the completion block:

```
if (completionBlock) {
    completionBlock(YES, someResult, nil); // or whatever values you need to send
}
```

This code ensure your app doesn't crash if someone calls:

```
NSURLSessionDataTask *test =  [weatherApiClient getForecastAndConditionsForZipCode:@"55345" withCompletionBlock:nil];
```

Comment: That is essentially what I did.  The only issue is xcode does not let you fill it in, you need to actually type it out manually to work.  Thank you, I got it to work?